# find the sum of intervals of time for multiple categories oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a Oracle database that saves every time a user makes an operation and I want to know how many hours each of them are working. My logic to find this number is the following: For every operation done in a 10 minute timespan, that time is considered as "working time".

So, if someone makes an operation at 10:05 and another at 10:25, I will be considering that he worked from 10:00-10:10 and from 10:20-10:30, 20 minutes total.

I want to have a query that calculates the total of minutes, following this logic, dividing for each user.

I tried following [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/group-rows-into-n-minute-intervals-with-sql), and was able to achieve the expected result, with only one user, however. Once I tried to include multiple users, the query would run infinitely. Below is the query that worked, with only one user.

How can I be able to replicate this logic, with multiple users?

```
WITH database AS(
SELECT
    operation_date,
    user
FROM
    database
where 
    user = 'user1'
)
    ,start_date as (
  select 
  min (operation_date ) AS start_date,
         10 / 1440 AS time_interval
  from   database
)
, intervals as (
  select 
  
  start_date + ( ( level - 1 ) * time_interval ) start_date,
         start_date + ( ( level ) * time_interval ) end_date
  from   start_date
  connect by level <= 144
)

,timesum as(
  select
     user,
     to_char(start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'),
     count ( operation_date ) as oper_num
  from   intervals
  left  join database
  on     start_date <= operation_date
  and    operation_date < end_date
  group  by user, start_date
  order  by start_date
  )
  
  select
  user,
  (count(oper_num)*10)/60 as hours
  from timesum
  where
  oper_num > 0
  group by user
```

Comment: calling a table even a cte table database, is not good and very confusing

Comment: If you just want the totals (not the exact intervals) and the intervals are constant (not based on the user's first action), you could probably just do something like https://dbfiddle.uk/bXXlkx4L which just takes the floor (to 10 minute intervals) of each `operation_date` and counts the distinct values per user. If this helps you, let me know and I'll clean it up and write up a proper answer.

Comment: This answer is much simpler and easier than my example. It worked great! I just needed to also subtract the seconds from the date by subtracting `TO_CHAR(DATA_MOV, 'SS')/(24*60*60)` and it reached the exact result I expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my comment seemed to help, I'm writing it up as an answer.

Since you only want the totals and since the periods seem to be 10 minute intervals relative to midnight (as opposed to being relative to the user's first action), all you need to do is round the times to the 10 minute floor and then count the distinct values. You can do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT 
  "USER", 
  COUNT(DISTINCT operation_date - MOD(TO_CHAR(operation_date, 'MI'), 10)/(24*60) - TO_CHAR(operation_date, 'SS')/(24*60*60)) * 10/60 t
FROM "DATABASE"
GROUP BY "USER"
ORDER BY "USER"
```

You can see it [working in this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6zd9hTsE).

`- MOD(TO_CHAR(operation_date, 'MI'), 10)/(24*60)` will get the 10 minute floor for minutes (e.g. 10:23:01 -> 10:20:01) and `- TO_CHAR(operation_date, 'SS')/(24*60*60)` will remove the seconds (e.g. 10:20:01 -> 10:20:00). Then by counting the distinct values for each user, you know how many 10 minute time periods they were working for and can calculate the total time.

(In the comments, my original version of this did not account for seconds, but it's cleaned up here. I also had an error in my day<->minutes arithmetic for rounding the minutes.)

This could probably be cleaned up more to use `interval` instead of the `24*60` and `24*60*60` arithmetic and to explicitly use `to_number` instead of relying on automatic conversion. But some of that will be preference and some of that will depend on the actual context where/how you're using this.

I kept the column/table names from the question. As others have noted in the comments and in the other answer, actually using these names is not a good idea since it will just cause confusion and unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Below I suggest a slightly different approach. Here I dynamically calculate a set of "time ranges" defined by hour and start minute/end minute. This is joined to the operational data and then the number of joined rows determines the number of working periods for each user & date. This approach is not only multi-user it also allows the freedom to choose any date range from the operational data.

```
WITH RANGES AS (
  -- creates a row for each 10 minute interval within a day
  SELECT
        START_HOUR
      , START_MINUTE
      , CASE WHEN END_MINUTE = 0 THEN 60 ELSE END_MINUTE END END_MINUTE
  FROM (
    SELECT
        EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST((TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + (LEVEL - 1) / 144) AS TIMESTAMP)) start_hour
      , EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST((TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + (LEVEL - 1) / 144) AS TIMESTAMP)) start_minute
      , EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST((TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + (LEVEL) / 144) AS TIMESTAMP)) end_minute
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 144
    )
  )
SELECT 
    USER_ID
  , TRUNC(operation_date)
  , COUNT(*) AS ACTIVE_PERIODS
FROM OPS_DATA
INNER JOIN RANGES 
    ON  extract(HOUR from cast(operation_date as timestamp) ) = RANGES.start_hour
    AND extract(MINUTE from cast(operation_date as timestamp) ) >= start_minute
    AND extract(MINUTE from cast(operation_date as timestamp) ) < end_minute
-- WHERE operation_date >= ?? and operation_date < ?? -- optional
GROUP BY
    USER_ID
  , TRUNC(operation_date)
```

| USER_ID | TRUNC(OPERATION_DATE) | ACTIVE_PERIODS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 01-JUL-23 | 2 |
| user2 | 01-JUL-23 | 2 |
| user3 | 01-JUL-23 | 1 |
| user1 | 02-JUL-23 | 2 |
| user2 | 02-JUL-23 | 2 |
| user3 | 02-JUL-23 | 1 |
| user1 | 03-JUL-23 | 2 |
| user2 | 03-JUL-23 | 2 |
| user3 | 03-JUL-23 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GY0tofjU)

**nb** I have assumed that the table of operational information is called "ops_data" and that the column operation_date is a "date data type". I also used "user_id" as the column name as "user" is a reserved word. Please view the linked fiddle for the sample data used and intermediate query reults which may help to explain the logic.